# Displaying XML in the Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, display, xml

I love the Chrome browser, but I use XML quite a lot in my development work and when I view it in Chrome I just get the rendered text.

I know that the source view is slightly better, but I'd really like to see the layout and functionality that Internet Explorer adds to XML, namely:

- Highlighting
- Open/close nodes

Any ideas how I can get this on Chrome?

---

**UPDATE:**

The XMLTree Extension is available on [Google Chrome Extension Beta Site](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en).

Comment: Hmm... uh, firefox?

Comment: come on guys - use firefox answers aren't really helpful.

Comment: Nice extension. Why don't you move your solution into its own answer, so you can accept it and it can be upvoted?

Comment: @arathorn - i have now added the plug-in as an answer - thanks.

Comment: @Josh: Don't you want to change your accepted answer, also? (I assume that's possible.)

Comment: @arathorn - no it's not possible as it was a featured question - thanks anyway :)

Comment: Enabled in Google Chrome 11 dev by default

Comment: Nowadays, accepting answers and bounties are no longer linked. So, feel free to accept your own answer instead!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess your best bet is to use a bookmarklet or install [Greasemetal](http://greasemetal.31tools.com/) (which is Firefox' Greasemonkey for Chrome), combined with a script like [XML Tree](http://userjs.org/scripts/general/developer_tools/xml-tree) (old, but [the source](http://userjs.org/scripts/download/general/developer_tools/xml-tree.user.js) may still help). A more generic syntax highlighting script may help as well, but I doubt if you'll easily find one with code folding.

Note that whitespace might matter in XML. Not all XML viewers respect that; [the screenshot](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/operaStuff/userjs/sampleXMLTree.png) created by the abovementioned XML Tree for [the example XML](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/operaStuff/userjs/samplexml.xml) does not respect it for the line *Sample XML element containing a lot of text, enough to be put on a separate line.*

(Unfortunately [jsgui.com/xml-viewer](http://jsgui.com/xml-viewer) is not responding while I am writing this.)

**EDIT**: [How to print pretty xml in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187451/how-to-print-pretty-xml-in-javascript/1187567#1187567) on Stack Overflow mentioned a newer version of XML Tree: [Pretty XML Tree](http://blog.webkitchen.cz/pretty-xml-tree), using XSLT and claims to be faster. The demo does not respond to clicking in my Safari or Firefox, but may be helpful anyway.

Comment: thanks - put me on the right track. got a working extension based on the xml tree script.

Comment: @Josh, though I'm not using Chrome: thanks for the plug-in!

Comment: i've updated my extension to use xslt and a simular idea to pretty xml tree - but i hope working better :) - let me know what you think - same link as before.

Comment: (I'm still not using Chrome, but given the earlier comments I read at http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/new-ext-xml-tree-user-friendly-xml-view-7963.html I'm sure people are happy!)

Answer (score 30):

I have now created a simple extension to add this functionality.

**UPDATE** see [here for the extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en).

Comment: Can you make it work for download links to XML files? Chrome keeps asking me to save the file to disk :(

Comment: Josh, that extension is now maintained by someone else?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand it the limitation is actually in the webkit rendering engine rather than in Chrome itself.  I doubt we'll decent XML rendering in Chrome before they properly launch extensions, at which time someone will be able to code a community extension to handle text/xml files.

If you want an alternative to IE, the Firefox rendering of XML is pretty good.

Comment: Either that, or they'll just create an extension equivalent to Firefox's "IE Tab," or perhaps "Firefox Tab" if you will. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419

Comment: @MatrixFrog FF-tab for chrome, in which you can run IE-Tab for FF? ;D

Answer (score 6):

If you right-click on a node, and click "Inspect Element", you should get the WebKit [Web Inspector](http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/), which has lots of fancy features including what you need; this should work for XML in addition to just HTML. Here's a screenshot from Safari, which has the same inspector:

[image: Web Inspector]

Comment: +1 this looks like the original poster's answer.  I just checked and the "inspect element" option is there when viewing a raw XML file.  It would be nice if this was the default rendering option for non HTML XML files; however two clicks isn't that much of a price to pay :)

Comment: very cool - just a shame its not the default option for xml.

Comment: Well, yeah. The problem is the browser has no way to know whether you want it to render the document or not, since XML is a perfectly valid medium for web pages (for example, http://homepage.mac.com/nathan_day/pages/news.xml). The Web Inspector is really just a developer tool (an awesome one!).

By the way, Josh, did this count as the answer to the original question?

Comment: It is a shame it's not the default renderer. Several times I have been forced to use IE for this purpose even though chrome is my browser of choice.

Regarding, how will the browser know how to display the document? I don't care! Somehow IE and Firefox figure it out. Maybe something in the stylesheet, guesswork, magic...just do it!

Comment: @jtbandes - the script idea from @Arjan van Bentem was the best answer as it helped create the extension which i've also added as an answer.

Comment: Hm, alright, though the Web Inspector is built in and doesn't require an extension. And it does more.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome dev channel now features an XML viewer, which is invoked if the XML does not have an associated XSL (the same holds for the WebKit nightlies). Happy viewing!

Comment: Yup! It's landed in the stable releases now I believe. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many, but only [XV — XML Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk) works for both regular XML and RSS feeds (if you turn it on in the settings).

Comment: That's great, that option was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No need for fancy extensions(Which breaks if you load a 1MB sized XML file).

This post is old, but right now Chrome has [fixed the bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434#c82) and has added support for viewing XML directly in the browser. Just drag and drop any [XML file](https://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=4340096000&name=test.xml&token=ABZ6GAfJq4ZNVmeG2Cc2XNLkiLw8hUGHog%3A1443516350793&id=434&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAee3YEFq0DZtV6U1Tbsb1L9uluEsA%3A1443516350793) and you can see the collapsible tree view of the file. It also supports viewing [RSS feeds](http://israblog.nana10.co.il/blog_rss.asp?blog=5).

Answer (score 0):

In my case (SharePoint 2013 REST API response ) **[XML Tree](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xml-tree/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en)** wins **XV — XML Viewer**

- perfect Tag matching and highlighting on mouse over
- unbeatable intuitive tree view format

Extra advanced features

- XPATH query

  [image]

(in fact i installed XV first and it did nothing with my xml, but XML tree rocks it)