# Why doesn't Chrome render RSS feeds?

Tags: google-chrome, rss

Chrome just shows text on properly formed RSS pages.  Browse over to

http://www.care2.com/greenliving/food-recipes/feed

for example.  Firefox and Explorer show the same page in a human friendly format.

Comment: I discovered doing QA on my site's RSS feeds.  There are versions of RSS feeds out there that do render properly in Chrome-- the NY Times feeds for example.  I haven't investigated reason for the difference, hoping someone would know...

Comment: right click -> view source, until they fix it.

Answer (score 8):

RSS feeds are planned for chromium/chrome. There is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84&q=rss&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone) in the chromium bug tracker for this. It looks like this isn't anything that they are in a real hurry on (the bug has been open for over a year). Of course, the alternative is to write it yourself and submit a patch. If it can get past codereview, you can get most anything in to the main repository.

EDIT: Looks like that bug has now been closed and the official answer is to use [this](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd) extension.

Comment: "356 people starred this issue..." 357 now.

Answer (score 1):

There are some bookmarklets over at http://feeds.ramisp.org/.

Answer (score 1):

[Displaying XML in Chrome Browser](https://superuser.com/questions/972/displaying-xml-in-chrome-browser)

The author of the above post created a Google Chrome extension (for the dev channel version only right now) that will render XML (e.g., RSS) into a tree like view, ala Firefox and IE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably by design. It just means support for the RSS format was not designed into Chrome.

Comment: RSS is not a protocol.

Comment: @whitequerk: you're right, it's not a protocol, it's a format but for all intents and purposes the answer was correct in essence.